# Instance launch failed - Dedicated Instance launches require a vCPU limit of at least 257

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm a complete beginner and trying to set up unreal engine's pixel streaming on aws. I am following a tutorial however, this appeared and I cannot continue.
[image: error message]

Why is it so high at 257? I know I should go and apply for a quota raise but I don't know if 257 isn't just too many.
I'll be using it for testing purposes so I think I don't need much.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You're trying to launch a dedicated instance. In other words you are trying to reserve a physical computer in Amazon's data center specifically for you, that no one else can use. The limit is high because that's the size of the physical computers they have in the data center. If you want a smaller computer, you will need to look into using a non-dedicated instance.

Comment: I see, I guess I'll try to use non-dedicated instance then